# Why the modal login does not close when click outside of the login box?

Tags: javascript, html, modalviewcontroller, simplemodal

I have called the js as shown as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal_style.css">
        <script src="modal_js.js"></script>
        <title>Modal Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Let's get started by</h1>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
        <div id="id01" class="modal">
            <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
```

My JavaScript file is as follows:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Please help me to identify the error

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

make a div and put the login div inside it and onclick on the first div make the both div

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none"
document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none"
```